# Python Unit test works With/without using side_effect

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I need to test a python script `script1.py` in which it imports my another class

```py
from lib.utils.ClassA import ClassA

lib = ClassA(xxxxxx)

lib.main()
```

Inside `ClassA` (ClassA.py) it imports python package `pyspark.sql.SparkSession`

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def main(self):
    self.create_table(xxx)
```

Here is my test:

```py
@patch("lib.utils.LibSparkSession.SparkSession")
def test_self(self, mock_spark):
    # arrange
    mock_spark.side_effect = mock_spark_session
    lib = ClassA("ref")
    lib.create_mapping_table = MagicMock()
        
    # action
    lib.main()
    
    # assert
    xxxxxxxx
```

For this line:

```py
mock_spark.side_effect = mock_spark_session
```

I tried to replace it with this:

```py
mock_spark = mock_spark_session
```

It also works.

Could someone explain why it works in both ways and which one is preferred?

Comment: sorry I cannot make the format working with this new text editor in SOF

Comment: Just select your code and press `Ctrl -K`